# Why isn't my MongoDB connecting to my python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to connect MongoDB to my program, but whenever I try adding a post into the database it gives me an error. I don't think I'm connecting it properly. I've seen a StackOverflow question just like this, but it still isn't working. I've replaced the password with my password and myFirstDatabase with the database name. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="+")

cluster = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://Hysan:myPassword@cluster0.dvbsy.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster["test"]
collection = db["test"]

post = {"_id": 0, "name": "username", "score": 5}
collection.insert_one(post)

@client.command()
async def add(ctx, time):
  print(time)

client.run('token :)')
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1394, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.sockets.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/phant/Programs/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    collection.insert_one(post)
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 705, in insert_one
    self._insert(document,
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 620, in _insert
    return self._insert_one(
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 609, in _insert_one
    self.__database.client._retryable_write(
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1552, in _retryable_write
    return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1438, in _retry_with_session
    return self._retry_internal(retryable, func, session, bulk)
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1462, in _retry_internal
    with self._get_socket(server, session) as sock_info:
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1308, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1331, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket(all_credentials)
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1397, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect(all_credentials)
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1297, in connect
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 820, in check_auth
    self.authenticate(credentials)
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 837, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 672, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 590, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram(credentials, sock_info, 'SCRAM-SHA-1')
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 333, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 710, in command
    return command(self, dbname, spec, secondary_ok,
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 158, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "D:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 167, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems is bad authentication:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

Are you using your username and password from Atlas as credentials?

You need to create a database user to grant an application or user, access to databases and collections in your clusters in this Atlas project.
Go to Database Access and add a new database user. Use that user and password here:

```
cluster = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://Hysan:myPassword@cluster0.dvbsy.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
```